# What do I need to do to clean/restore these floor tiles?

Tags: tile, floor, diy-vs-pro, porch

We have a porch on a 1930s property in the UK which has red tiles on the floor. I believe they are original and in good need of a clean up and maybe some additional work. What do I need to do to get them looking nice?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to seal the tiles and add a new sheen to the tiles is with Boiled Linseed Oil. These tiles are likely quarry tiles rather than the more modern replacement terracotta tiles.

You can buy modern products that do that same job.

See this link https://lubelska.co.uk/how-to-seal-a-reclaimed-brick-or-terracotta-floor/

Comment: I guess Danish Oil wouldn't work instead of Boiled Linseed Oil?

Comment: @JamesCross I've never seen Danish Oil mentioned as an alternative. We have a few areas in our house with these tiles so did research this topic.